# Fetch goes to then prematurely when getting html

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, nginx, fetch-api

Im using fetch to populate a page with html, backend server is selfhosted, dns with cloudflare and using nginx, running on node, express, and ejs, but suddenly yesterday it started moving on before the full body of the fetch was finished.

Here is the function I use on the front end to fetch and decode the html

```
function fetchWindow(element) {
    let link = element.getAttribute('data-nav-link');
    let checked = element.checked;

    console.log('fetchWindow');
    console.log(link, checked);

    //adds a loading animation
    document.querySelector('.render-content').innerHTML = `<div class='loader'><div class="line-wobble"></div></div>`;

    //gets inner html based on checked state
    if(checked) {
        //gets html from link
        fetch(`./dashboard/${link}`, {
            method: 'GET',
            credentials: 'same-origin'
        }).then((res) => {

            // makes a toast if the response is not ok
            if(!res.ok) {
                M.toast({html: `Error ${res.status}: ${res.headers.get('err')}`, classes: `red darken-4`});
                return;
            }

            //reads the response body
            res.body.getReader().read().then((data) => {
                let html = new TextDecoder("utf-8").decode(data.value);
                document.querySelector('.render-content').innerHTML = html;
                init();
            }).catch((err) => {
                console.log(err);
            });
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
        });
    }
        
}
```

Ive checked the endpoint and it is generating and sending out the full html as well as the browser is receiving the full html, although the network tab of inspect also shows the fetch being completed before it actually is and the listed size and real size of the body are off by a factor of four.  Ive tried just using setTimeout, but that doesnt work consistently.  I've also tried with proxy_buffering in both states and it makes no meaningful difference, I read on another post it could be data getting delayed and sending a empty body causing the browser to assume the fetch was complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.read().then()` gets the next chunk of data, not necessarily all the data.  See example [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ReadableStream/getReader).

So, you have to set it up to read all the chunks, not just the first one.  An example for how to do that is shown in the above MDN reference.

This would also explain why the size of the data is off (because you are only reading the first chunk, not all of the data).